# Storing Questions and Answers for Tutorial application in android

Tags: android, android-storage

I am developing new android application for Java tutorials. I wanted to know what is the best way to store questions and answers. I am planning to have around 100 questions for each sections. I am totally having 5 sections.

Thinking of below options. But don't know what would be the performance

1. Storing in Sqlite database - But in this case, how to insert the questions?
2. Storing it in excel file and reading the excel using poi and showing it in the application
3. Storing it as JSON file ( one json file for each section)
4. Storing it in XML file ( one xml for each section)

Could someone please help me on this which is the best one to choose?

Answer (score 1):

Use JSON buddy.

```
[
{"SectionTitle":"Section A",
"questions":
[{"title":"What is Java?"
"answers": [{"title":"programming language", "isCorrect":"true"},{"title":"cooking technique","isCorrect":"false"},{"title":"movie star","isCorrect":"false"}]
},...]
},...
]
```

and parse your json into objects, use recyclerView to view your sections, and a ViewPager to move between questions.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. let me try and let you know

Comment: sure thing. let me know how it goes. but make sure you organize and well form your objects